# initWithNibName not working

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder

Just ran into this very frustrating problem when trying to add a new view, I have 2 different types of view: `LargeCoverViewController` and `CoverViewController`.

I created a `LargeCoverViewController` like this:

```
LargeCoverViewController *tmpCover = [[LargeCoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LargeCoverViewController" bundle:nil andIssue:issue];
```

That just works, but when I try to create a `CoverViewController`, it refuses to work

```
CoverViewController *tmpCover = [[CoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CoverViewController" bundle:nil andIssue:issue];
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with the .xib file, when I do like this it "works" again

```
CoverViewController *tmpCover = [[CoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LargeCoverViewController" bundle:nil andIssue:issue];
```

In Interface Builder the class is set properly, my view is linked up correctly. (It's basically just a copy of the LargeCoverViewController), am I still missing something?
It's getting very frustrating ...

EDIT:
My application doesn't crash, if my nibname was wrong the application should crash, which isn't the case here.

Comment: Refuses to work? I bet that's not the error message you're getting? What is the problem?

Comment: @Rog, Jup, it refuses the work, nothing is happening, my view remains empty. The viewDidLoad is getting called, just nothing is showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating new separate XIB file rather copying whole XIB file and then copy the UI outlets and views from other XIB to this newly created XIB file.

Sometimes, Xcode gets confused with copy-pasting. I know this is not proper solution but sometimes it works. :)

Comment: Well that seems to work, although I never copied the XIB file (just created my own), did the same thing now and it works ...

Comment: I agree with BornCoder that Xcode get confused sometimes with copy-pasting.  I've actually had outlets not copy over when pasting and spent many hours trying to figure out what was broken.  Always check your outlets.

Answer (score 0):

When copying ViewController, the **fileowner's custom class** remains the same so change it to your new ViewController and once again bind your view after changing.

Comment: I didn't copy it (It looks the same), I checked the file owner's class a million times, it's set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application getting crashed on that line? Check the console for the logs. You may have got error messages or crash logs.

If you copied XIB resources from any other XIB then  check for the linked outlets with objects which may not be available to this new class.

I hope this will help you and will able to resolve the issue.

Comment: My application does not crash, all the functions are geting called correctly, just nothing is being displayed when I use `CoverViewController` as a nib name.

Comment: If that class is of **UIViewController** then check if **-(void)ViewDidLoad** is getting called?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is being called

Comment: If you have connected IBOutlets with XIB file then check if those are allocated in viewDidLoad.

Comment: The IBOulets seem to be working fine, it seems like everything works fine, just nothing is being displayed